# glazedlists with ID in java

Tags: java, swing, glazedlists

I am using `glazedlists` for JComboBox in java to make a JComboBox searchable and sortable. But there is situation I can't get to solve it.

I have a `JComboBox` attached with `glazedlists`. glazedlists  takes String array to fill this combobox and make it searchable like this

```
String[] Values = {"ABC", "DEF", "GHI", "JKL", "MNO"};
JComboBox cmb = new JComboBox();
AutoCompleteSupport.install(cmb , GlazedLists.eventListOf(Values));
```

This works good but the problem is that I want to add **ID** along with value coming from Database and for that I am implementing my own custom **ListCellRenderer** like this

```
class MyListRenderer extends JLabel implements ListCellRenderer 
{
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        Object[] itemData = (Object[])value;
        setText((String)itemData[1]);
        return this;
    }
}
cmb.setRenderer(new MyListRenderer());
```

And to add value in JComboBox, I have to

```
while(rs.next()){
    int id=rs.getInt("company_id");
    String category=rs.getString("company_name");
    Object[] itemData = new Object[] {id, category};
    cmb.addItem(itemData);
}
```

Now how can I implement my `JComboBox` with `glazedlists` while setting my own custom renderer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't have any success with your way, but I found a solution in an earlier project. You can set the model of the JComboBox instead by doing something like this:

```
//load the list of objects to use
ContainerClass[] allOptions = ContainerClass.getAll();

//create an EventList with this list and set is as the combobox model
final EventList<ContainerClass> eventList = GlazedLists.eventList(Arrays.asList(allOptions));
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel<ContainerClass>(allOptions));

//finally initialize the combobox by SwingUtilities if done on a non-UI thread
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        AutoCompleteSupport<ContainerClass> install = 
                AutoCompleteSupport.install(comboBox, eventList);
        install.setFilterMode(TextMatcherEditor.CONTAINS);
        install.setHidesPopupOnFocusLost(true);
        install.setSelectsTextOnFocusGain(false);
        install.setCorrectsCase(false);
    }
});
```

And with a ContainerClass like:

```
class ContainerClass{
     int id;
     String company;

     //helper method to get all the objects needed
     static ContainerClass[] getAll(){
          ContainerClass test = new ContainerClass();
          test.id = 2;
          test.company = "abc";
          return new ContainerClass[]{test,test,test};
     }

     @Override
     //this String is what actually will be displayed in the combobox
     public String toString(){return "(" + id + ") " + company;}
}
```

And I'm assuming that your JComboBox has the following type:

```
JComboBox<ContainerClass> comboBox;
```

*(I had to obfuscate the names of all variables, so there might be errors in the code. Let me know and I will correct them)*

So to recap. GlazedLists uses the model to get the names, which again asks the *ContainerClass* for it's toString() method which will return the name to display in the JComboBox.

As a note, when you call *comboBox.getSelectedItem()* it will return an object of type *ContainerClass*, or null if it isn't a valid selection.

**UPDATE**

If you want to be able to control the order as well as the name, you would need to implement your own model for the ComboBox. Found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/JComboBoxUsingtheCustomModel.htm) that seems to explain it well:

```
class MyComboBoxModel extends AbstractListModel implements ComboBoxModel {   
  String[] ComputerComps = { "Monitor", "Key Board", "Mouse", "Joy Stick", 
                 "Modem", "CD ROM", "RAM Chip", "Diskette" };

  String selection = null;

  public Object getElementAt(int index) {
    return ComputerComps[index];   
  }

  public int getSize() {
    return ComputerComps.length;   
  }

  public void setSelectedItem(Object anItem) {
    selection = (String) anItem; // to select and register an   
  } // item from the pull-down list

  // Methods implemented from the interface ComboBoxModel   
  public Object getSelectedItem() {
       return selection; // to add the selection to the combo box   
  } 
}
```

Comment: How would you sort items in glazedLists for JComboBox using your method?

Comment: Doesn't it respect the order of the array you feed it? If so you should be able to sort it however you want before creating the model.

Comment: I already gave it a sorted array but this shuffles every item in it.

Comment: Updated with example of a custom model as well.